# How can I mark constant as used on the outside for Resharper?

Tags: resharper, external

I have color constants in my WPF class library. How can I mark its as used on the outside for Resharper?

Comment: What do you mean by 'as used on the outside'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that ReSharper highlights the constants as unused, try using [ReSharper annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html).

If I recall correctly, you need to mark the constants with `[UsedImplicitly]` attribute to make ReSharper assume that they have external usages.